# Django: Decoupling Permission-Check from Calling the View

Tags: django, permissions

## Django: Decoupling Permission-Check from Calling the View

I would like to decouple the permission checking in django.

Current draw-back: If you use decorators like  [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required), then you can't know in advance whether a user has the permission to do so or not.

I would like to split this into two steps:

1. check permissions
2. call the view.

## Use Case 1: Admin tool

I want an tool for admins where they can check the access-permissions of users. This requires:

1. The check must not use the current `request.user` since this is the wrong user object.
2. The check must not actually call the view, since this might alter data.

## Use Case 2: Show Link as disabled.

I want to show links as disabled (grayed out and without "href") if a user does not have the permission to see linked page.

## Dream

Returning a boolean for "ok" and "permission denied" is nice. But the big benefit would be if the admin could get a **reason**.

Example:

1. Admin opens "Check Perm Tool"
2. He selects a view/URL
3. The admin hits "submit"

Result:

```
------------------------------
| User     | Allowed | Reason
------------------------------
| fooadmin |  Yes    | is_superuser
| foouser  |  No     | missing permission "view-bar-at-midnight"
| foobar   |  Yes    | User has permission "view-bar-at-midnight"
```

## Question

How to get this dream come true?

... Just for the records, I posted the idea on the django-develop list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/rpTh4G3BgIQ

Comment: Its unclear what you're asking about, if the user isn't logged in then they don't have permissions

Comment: @Sayse from what I understand, guettli wants a "View website as X" feature (where X is any user).

Comment: So, I'm not sure how you want the permissions check to work in **Use Case 1**. If you're fine with the Django Admin interface, at `http://domain/admin`, then this is solved by adding a Boolean variable (or some value if you have more varieties of permissions) for permissions  in your User model, which you're able to view in a table on the admin interface with the use of a [Model Admin Object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) in `admin.py`.

Comment: I may not have been clear:
In User Model:
`has_permission = self.is_admin()` (or whichever authentication check you need, or can to write), so you could then, in admin.py:
`class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):`
    `list_display = ('name', 'has_permission')`, or something like that.

I think the link display could just be solved through some if-then logic in your template, by passing in the right variables from your view, provided you have your permissions variable. It's an inelegant solution, but could be cleaned up.
`{% if user.has_permission %}`
    `<div class=""> </div>`
 `{% else %}`

Comment: Have you had a look at the django-roles-premission module? Would it be helpful ? https://django-role-permissions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: @Why I looked at the docs of django-role-permissions. It handles the mapping between users and permissions and it gives you a decorator for views. But I don't see that the app decouples the permissions for a view from calling it. AFAIK it gives me no way to query a view which permissions would be required.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you already have a list of all the permissions needed to view each view/URL? i.e. You know that URL `/bar` requires permissions `superuser` and `view-bar-at-night` ahead of time?

If so, try adding a `ViewPermissions` model to `models.py` first:

```
from django.db import models

class ViewPermissions(models.Model):
    view_url = models.CharField(help_text="The URL of this view")
```

Then in `admin.py`:

```
from models import ViewPermissions
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms

class ViewPermissionFormField(forms.ModelForm):
    permissions = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("Permissions", is_stacked=False),
        queryset=models.Permission.objects.all()
    )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        extra_field = self.cleaned_data.get('extra_field', None)
    return super(ViewPermissionFormField, self).save(commit=commit)

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = ViewPermissions

class ViewPermissionsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ViewPermissionsFormField
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': 'view_url', 'permissions'
        })
    )
```

Now you can add permissions to each view URL in admin to keep track of things. FYI you can [create your own custom permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#programmatically-creating-permissions) and add them to Django's existing ones.

You can create an admin form that pulls up the users, lists their permissions, then leverages `ViewPermissions` to see what URLs that user can visit based on what permissions they have (Use case 1).

You can now check the user's permission in your view function (or class if that's how you're defining your views) like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from models import ViewPermissions

def my_view(request)
    view_url = request.get_current_url()
    permissions_required = ViewPermissions.objects.filter(view_url = view_url).permissions
    context['user_permissions'] = []
    for p in permissions_required:
        if request.user.has_permission(p):
            context['user_permissions'].append(p)
```

Now you can pass those permissions into your template and grey out links accordingly (Use case 2).

So something like that might work...

Edit:

The link to Django docs no longer available. One might visit [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#programmatically-creating-permissions) instead.